# How can I add child on another child of canvas in create js

Tags: javascript, createjs

This code is not working and does not look appropriate for adding child on another child.

```
var child1 = new createjs.Shape();
child1.graphics.beginStroke("#0066FF").beginFill("#CCCCCC").drawRect(60,253, 25,24);
stage,addChild(child1);
stage.update();
var child2 = new createjs.Text("ABS","bold 22px Arial");
stage.addChild(child2);
stage.update();
```

Comment: What is your error exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a `,` instead of a `.`:

```
stage,addChild(child1);
```

Try

```
stage.addChild(child1);
```

Comment: Also, you only need to update the stage once, or any time the content changes and needs to be redrawn.